# Sbyte[] vs byte[][] using methods

Tags: c#, web-services, arrays

It is written

```
byte[][] getImagesForFields(java.lang.String[] fieldnames)
```

Gets an array of images for the given fields.

On the other hand, as long as I use the method in the web application project built on asp.net 2.o using c#;

the provided web method declared above, returns sbyte;
Have a look my code below;

```
  formClearanceService.openSession(imageServiceUser);
  formClearanceService.prepareInstance(formId);
  byte[][] fieldImagesList = formClearanceService.getImagesForFields(fieldNames);
  formClearanceService.closeSession();
```

thus I get the following error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'sbyte[]' to 'byte[][]'

So now,
1- should I ask the web service provider what is going on?
or
2- any other way that can use the sbyte as I was suppose to use byte[][] like following using:
byte[] ssss = fieldImagesList [0]..

Comment: Who has provided this function?  Looks like the documentation (assuming that's where the first quote comes from) and the code are out of sync.  You'll need to ask the library author what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @Paolo it is a documentation. After a while I am going to ask them unless I get an answer from stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has signed bytes, so that part is correct in some ways (although unsigned bytes are more natural) - but it is vexing that it is returning a single array rather than a jagged array. I expect you're going to have to compare some data to see what you have received vs what you expected.

But changing between signed and unsigned can be as simple as:

```
sbyte[] orig = ...
byte[] arr = Array.ConvertAll(orig, b => (byte)b);
```

or (faster) simply:

```
sbyte[] orig = ...
byte[] arr = new byte[orig.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(orig, 0, arr, 0, orig.Length);
```

Comment: it is right, the web service is java based and the web application side is built on asp.net platform using c#.